# Swagger - how do I define a byte[][] in a response component

Tags: swagger, openapi

If I'm describing "public byte[] Data" I do so as:

```
Data:
  type: string
  format: base64
  description: "The generated report as a single file in the user specified format. If this is populated Pages will be null."
```

But how do I describe a 2 dimensional array like "public byte[][] Pages"?

Answer (score 0):

Usually multidimensional array is used for Request component but for the Response component the array will be flatted as single array of bytes.

Anyway you could achieve with the following code :

```
Data:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
    format: base64
    description: "The generated report as a single file in the user specified format."
```